# Does opentok provide thumbnails for archives?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, html5-video, opentok, tokbox

I have the [opentok-archiving](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/) sample application set up. While playing the archives, I need thumbnails for the archive. Does OpenTok provide thumbnails?

Currently, I think the only way is to setup `Archiving URL callback`, and once the archive status is changed to `uploaded`, I need to get a thumbnail out of the video on my backend.

Are there any other better ways to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

(Myself: tokbox developer)

No, OpenTok does not provide a thumbnail of the archives. However, you can create the thumbnails yourself very easily with [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video).